# How to collect and improve Jenkins Pipeline Groovy jobs performance (threads, resources, unreleased memory)

Tags: java, performance, jenkins, groovy, automation

I'm develop and run Jenkins pipeline jobs using Groovy, our code executes multiple threads and required high CPU and memory.

The code runs on the Jenkins agent.

I'm looking for a solution (tool or code) that points to the weaknesses of source code lines so I can optimize my Jenkins builds.